# ASP Calendar date from text field to calendar

Tags: asp-classic, calendar

Hello guys I tried to do it myself but for this I didn't know what I had to do. So basically what I need to do is create a text field a button and a calendar. So I have done almost everything but I need to make it when a date is typed in the text field and I submit it the calendar updates. so far I only got the date in the text field when clicking on a date but this is not what I need. Any help is appreciated thank you

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a Classic ASP specific question, what you're really after is a Javascript date picker component. Something like this [JQuery Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) will do exactly what you're after.

Usage:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>


</body>
</html>
```